# Excel VBA: Write 2D array to another worksheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a VBA function that creates a 2D array `res`. I'd like to write the array data to another worksheet, not the current worksheet the function is executed from. This should be pretty straightforwards but i'm new to VBA.

The code ends on the last line without an error message or writing any data.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Output")

Dim out As Range
Set out = ws.Range("A1")
out.Resize(UBound(res, 1), UBound(res, 2)).Value = res
```

Comment: If you are calling that function from a cell, you cannot alter the value of a different cell.

Comment: Your code worked for me. Check to make sure you have valid values in `res`.

Comment: Yes, code works. It may be useful to see the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code should work.

Does `Res` actually contain data?

Sample below that populates an array, checks if it is more than one cell, then dumps back to the worksheet.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim res

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Input")
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Output")

Set rng1 = ws.Range("A1:B10")

If rng1.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    res = rng1.Value2
    ws1.[a1].Resize(UBound(res, 1), UBound(res, 2)).Value2 = res
End If
```